# ASP NET Sessions throw error with .ToString()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm have problemas to work with Session in my project ASp.NEt c# in IE9.
Sometimes occured error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of as object"

Other problem is that in IE9, sometimes not save my Session to change Idiom to others pages.
In Chrome all works good!

[image: Error]

[image]

Below is my Page_Load and CarregaGrid(). This problem occured in sometimes, no all time, and in any page no in all page or just in one specific page.

```
    public void CarregaGrid()
{
    var listByGroupM = new ManageUsers().ConsultUsersGroupM();
    if (listByGroupM != null)
    {
        this.GridView1.DataSource = listByGroupM;
        if (listByGroupM.Count != 0)
        {
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
    }

    if (divModify.Visible == true)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string idioma = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString();

            if (Session["idioma"].ToString() != null)
            {
                idioma = Session["idioma"].ToString();
            }

            Idioma.MudaCultura(idioma);

            Button btnDelete = (Button)row.FindControl("btnDelete");
            btnDelete.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnDelete");

            string UserName = row.Cells[1].Text;
            PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "x.com", "x", "xxx");
            UserPrincipal insUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(insPrincipalContext, UserName);

            if (insUserPrincipal == null)
            {
                row.Cells[2].Text = "";
                row.Cells[3].Text = "";
            }

            else
            {
                string Email = insUserPrincipal.EmailAddress;
                row.Cells[2].Text = Email;
                string DisplayName = insUserPrincipal.DisplayName;
                row.Cells[3].Text = DisplayName;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string idioma = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString();

        if (Session["idioma"].ToString() != null)
        {
            idioma = Session["idioma"].ToString();
        }

        Idioma.MudaCultura(idioma);
        Label1.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("lblUserAdd");
        CarregaGrid();
    }
}

protected void pt_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Idioma.MudaCultura("pt");
    Label1.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("lblUserAdd");
    CarregaGrid();
    Session["idioma"] = "pt";
}

protected void en_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Idioma.MudaCultura("en");
    Label1.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("lblUserAdd");
    CarregaGrid();
    Session["idioma"] = "en";
}

protected void es_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Idioma.MudaCultura("es");
    Label1.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("lblUserAdd");
    CarregaGrid();
    Session["idioma"] = "es";
}
```

Comment: Doing `Session["idioma"].ToString() ` will throw error when `Session["idioma"]` is `null`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replace

```
if (Session["idioma"].ToString() != null)
```

with

```
if (Session["idioma"] != null)
```

If the `session object` is `NULL`, then calling `.ToString()` will throw an **error**.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
if (Session["idioma"].ToString() != null)
```

to:

```
if (Session["idioma"] != null)
```